# Bitbucket search repo API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I've been trying to find an API to query repositories on BitBucket based on language they're written in. Few years ago I've been using

```
https://bitbucket.org/repo/all/relevance?language=X
```

But right now the link is dead.

There is a new API under

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories
```

But theres no documentation on any query parameters.

Is there any way to browse public repos?

Comment: No, at this moment there is no way to browse repositories on Bitbucket without using the search function. You might want to vote/watch issue [#2934](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/2934/browse-search-repositories-by-language).

Comment: Could You add this as an answer for subsequent people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at this moment there is no way to browse repositories on Bitbucket without using the search function. There is a proposal to add such a feature, expressed in issue [#2934](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/2934/browse-search-repositories-by-language), which you might want to vote/watch.

On the API side, you can browse all public repositories using the endpoint `https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/`, but you can't search and/or filter results.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when the API changed, but you can now do this by using the following syntax

`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/USER_NAME?q=language=%22LANGUAGE%22`

`%22` is the decoded version of `"`

For a bit more information on filtering the request, refer to:

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/filtering#supp-endpoints

---

You can click on this link for a working example:

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/craigiswayne?q=language=%22shell%22

Should only bring back my public repositories that are set with `shell` language